# Could not find matching function to call loaded model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, model, tf.keras

I trained a deep neural network using a custom object and was able to successfully train it however when I saved and try to reload the model for retraining, I got the subject of the post as an error.
I've tried using TensorFlow to create a get_config to

```
class SkipCon(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, size, reduce = True, deep = 3, skip_when=0, activation="relu", **kwargs):
   
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.activation = keras.activations.get(activation) # used to combine
    # skip connections and cascaded dense layers
    self.main_layers =[]
    self.skip_when = skip_when #to be used in call as a control
    if reduce:
      for _ in range(deep):
        self.main_layers.extend([
          keras.layers.Dense(size, activation=activation, 
                              use_bias=True),
          keras.layers.BatchNormalization()])

        # Reduce the input size by two each time, if the
        # network is to be designed deeper and narrow
        size = size/2
    else:
      for _ in range(deep):
        self.main_layers.extend([
        keras.layers.Dense(size, activation=activation, 
                            use_bias=True),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization()])
        
    self.skip_layers = []
    if skip_when > 0:
      if reduce:
        size = size*2 # since the size of skipped connection  
                      # should match with cascaded dense
      self.skip_layers = [
          keras.layers.Dense(size, activation=activation, 
                          use_bias=True),
          keras.layers.BatchNormalization()]

  def call(self, inputs):
    Z = inputs
    for layer in self.main_layers:
      Z = layer(Z)
    if not self.skip_when:
      return self.activation(Z)
    skip_Z = inputs
    for layer in self.skip_layers:
      skip_Z = layer(skip_Z)
    return self.activation(Z + skip_Z)
  
  def get_config(self):
        return {"Z": self.activation}
  @classmethod  
  def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)
```

Skip connection created

```
user_layer = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', use_bias = True)(feature_layer_users)
# Add a Skip Connection
user_layer = SkipCon(size = 256, deep = 2, reduce = False, skip_when=1, activation="relu")(user_layer)
user_layer = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(user_layer) # Way to handle overfitting
user_layer = SkipCon(size = 256, deep = 2, reduce = True, skip_when=1, activation="relu")(user_layer)
user_layer = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(user_layer)
user_layer = SkipCon(size = 64, deep = 2, reduce = True, skip_when=0, activation="relu")(user_layer)


item_layer = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu', use_bias = True)(feature_layer_items)
# Add a Skip Connection
item_layer = SkipCon(size = 256, deep = 2, reduce = False, skip_when=1, activation="relu")(item_layer)
item_layer = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(item_layer) # Way to handle overfitting
item_layer = SkipCon(size = 256, deep = 2, reduce = True, skip_when=1, activation="relu")(item_layer)
item_layer = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(item_layer)
item_layer = SkipCon(size = 64, deep = 2, reduce = True, skip_when=0, activation="relu")(item_layer)


combined = tf.concat([user_layer, item_layer], axis =-1)

both_layer = SkipCon(size = 128, deep = 2, reduce = False, skip_when=1, activation="relu")(combined)
both_layer = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(both_layer)
both_layer = SkipCon(size = 64, deep = 2, reduce = False, skip_when=1, activation="relu")(combined)
both_layer = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(both_layer)
both_layer = SkipCon(size = 16, deep = 2, reduce = False, skip_when=0, activation="relu")(both_layer)

z = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")(both_layer)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_user, input_items], outputs=z)
```

Saving model

```
model.save("my_model")
```

Reloading model

```
model = keras.models.load_model('my_model', custom_objects={"SkipCon":SkipCon})
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your `get_config(self)` function should match the arguments of your custom layer. I couldn't completely replicate your example as I’m missing your input layers, but adjusting the get_config function allowed me to properly load the model after saving it.

```
class SkipCon(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, size, reduce = True, deep = 3, skip_when=0, activation="relu", **kwargs):
   
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.size = size

... 

  def get_config(self):
        return {"size": self.size}
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37973
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#custom_objects

Comment: I've tried to reconstruct the get_config. the same error is still returning. Can I send you the whole script to look at it? if it's possible. I'll appreciate

Comment: Sure, are you able to update the example with the rest? I only ask as it might help others in the future.

Comment: can you send me your email please so I can share the script? I've updated the script but still returning the same error. I even tried to load it without the custom class, still returned same error.